# Grab array value if a specific key is there with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks something like this:

```
Array
(
    [100] => Array
        (
            [room_id] => 100
            [name] => Town Center
        )

    [110] => Array
        (
            [room_id] => 110
            [name] => Coffee Shop
            [pin_id] => 7146
            [pin_x] => 570
            [pin_y] => 150
        )
)
```

I was wondering if there was a way that I could obtain a specific value, if the "pin_id" key was there. So for example:

```
Array
(
    [100] => Array
        (
            [room_id] => 100
            [name] => Town Center     <-- No "pin_id" so I DON'T need this value
        )

    [110] => Array
        (
            [room_id] => 110
            [name] => Coffee Shop     <-- I want to OBTAIN this value
            [pin_id] => 7146          <-- Since the "pin_id" key is here
            [pin_x] => 570
            [pin_y] => 150
        )
)
```

I've tried using foreach, but it gets to complicated for me. I'm still very new with arrays, and not so familiar with the terminology/functions.

Answer (score 1):

Easy use the `PHP` function [`array_key_exists`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

You may have to go through a `foreach` loop since you are using a multidimensional array:

```
$names = [];
foreach($array as $e)
{
  if(array_key_exists('pin_id', $e)) {
        echo "The 'pin_id' element is in the array";
      $names[] = $e['name'];
  }
}
```

And now `$names` include all you names values

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($your_big_array as $arr) {
    if ($arr['pin_id'] == 'some_value') $i_need_this = $arr['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function search_key( $array, $key ) {
    $results = array();
    if ( is_array( $array ) ) {
        if ( isset( $array[$key] ) && $array[$key] == $key )
            $results[] = $array;
        foreach ( $array as $subarray )
            $results = array_merge( $results, tm_search_key_value( $subarray, $key ) );
    }
    return $results;
}
```

USAGE:

search_key( $array, 'pin_id');

Search specific KEY from Multidimentional, It will return array of that specific key.