# PHP grab multidimensional array key value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks something like this:

```
Array
(
    [100] => Array
        (
            [room_id] => 100
            [name] => Town Center
        )

    [110] => Array
        (
            [room_id] => 110
            [name] => Coffee Shop
            [pin_id] => 7146
            [pin_x] => 570
            [pin_y] => 150
        )
)
```

I was wondering if there was a way  that I could find the key for a specific value, if the "pin_id" value was there. For example:

```
Array
(
    [100] => Array
        (
            [room_id] => 100
            [name] => Town Center
        )

    [110] => Array                    <- I want to get this key "110"             
        (                                 
            [room_id] => 110          
            [name] => Coffee Shop     
            [pin_id] => 7146          <- Because "pin_id" is here
            [pin_x] => 570
            [pin_y] => 150
        )
)
```

Comment: Use the same loop as answered in your previous question but do `foreach ($array as $key => $arr)` then `$key` holds the key 110 which you're looking for.

Comment: Didn't you already post this question? Or, it's basically adding onto your first question. And, did your first queston get answered? If so, give credit where credit is due. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317879/grab-array-value-if-a-specific-key-is-there-with-php

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to pass your array through a loop and use `array_key_exists`.

```
function makeHappen($argument){
  //Array
    foreach ($argument as $val) {
      if(array_key_exists($val, $array)){
            //if key exists, do something
      }
    }
}
echo makeHappen('pin_id');
```

Comment: fix your foreach - the `$key` isn't coming from anywhere here...

Comment: you removed the key, `$val` is the value not key.